# Batch file to copy files

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Need to have a batch file that will actually check if the file name has "abc" in its name and if its there , then it will initiate a copy.
So suppose folder /test has 5 files

```
apt.text 
mar.text 
may.text 
Jan.text 
abc_xyx1234.text
```

So since "abc" appears in string only in the last file , it should pick only last one.
I tried

```
@echo off 
for /f %%a in (' dir /b /a-d ^| find /v /i "abc" ') copy "%%a" 
pause
```

but it didn't work out.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: thanks zb226.. here is what I have tried..

Comment: @echo off
for /f %%a in ( ' dir /b /a-d ^| find /v /i "abc" ' ) 
copy "%%a"
pause

Comment: What this means `It didn't work`? You get a blue screen? What do you expect for `copy "%%a"` ... should copy to which destination?

Comment: my source destination is /source  and target where I need to copy is /target
 source has files with all names , but I need to pick and copy that file to /target which has"abc" in its filename ..

Comment: findstr /source/batch:"abc" *.txt > NUL
if not errorlevel 1 xcopy *.* /target

this errors out 
FINDSTR: // ignored
FINDSTR: /a ignored
FINDSTR: /t ignored
FINDSTR: /c ignored
FINDSTR: /h ignored

Comment: @echo off
set k=test
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('find "%k%"^<"/source"') do (
set z=%%a
set z="!z:%k%=",!
call :1 !z!
)
goto :eof

:1
set w=%1
call :2 %~1
goto :eof

:2
set w=%~1
shift
if "%1" neq "" GOTO :2
ECHO FINAL RESULT: %w%



this is giving access denied

Comment: Any help apppreciated

Answer (score 3):

You have no destination for your copy.

The `find /v /i` will find those filesnames that do **not** (`/v`) match `abc`

It's probably easier to use

```
copy *abc* destination
```

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is the following:

Even though forward slashes work *sometimes*, **Windows' canonical path separator is the backslash `\`**. Using forward slashes as path separators confuses programs which use the forward slash as parameter prefix, and most if not all of the Microsoft Windows tools do so, including `FIND` and `FINDSTR`.

Also, if you're talking about `/folder` - which should be `\folder` as explained above - you're talking about a directory **in the root of the current drive**. I'm not sure you really mean that.

Apart from that, Magoo's suggestion is still kind of valid, but it omits the path "problem".

So let's use absolute directories to clarify:

I'll assume your source directory is `c:\work\source` and contains the file set you've stated in your question. I'll assume your target directory is `c:\stackoverflow\target`. So you can do the following from anywhere on your system:

```
copy c:\work\source\*abc* c:\stackoverflow\target
```

If you're doing this from an arbitrary folder on drive `c`, you could omit the drives:

```
copy \work\source\*abc* \stackoverflow\target
```

And, if you're inside the source folder, you could use Magoo's answer:

```
copy *abc* \stackoverflow\target
```